# Android max. size of custom notification

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, height

I'm trying to create some custom notifications for my app.

> Usually collapsed view layouts are limited to 64 dp, and expanded view layouts are limited to 256 dp.

Although I considered these restrictions, it seems that the notification is cut off on several phones as you can see in the screenshots below. 
I did some research on that because I thought there are also restrictions depending on different manufacturers or UIs, but couldn't find anything.

That's how it is implemented:

```
// 64dp is set for height
val collapsedView = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.custom_notification_collapsed)
// 256dp is set for height
val expandedView = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.custom_notification_expanded)

val customNotification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_map, "Personal", PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, personalIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_map, "Business", PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, businessIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_map, "Work", PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, businessIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
        .setColor(Color.parseColor("#00D8FF"))
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
        .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
        .setCustomBigContentView(expandedView)
        .build()

notificationManager.notify(4, customNotification)
```

Here's the result:

[Xiaomi Mi Mix2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnio2.png)

[Samsung Galaxy Note 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKqH0.jpg)

Now the questions are:
Did I fail the implementation somehow?
If not, is there a way to figure out the max. notification height for a current phone programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

`Notification` (your `RemoteView`) that you see is created by another process and only that process can know the size

There is no official way to get the max height for custom notification. I think the only way you can do is to reduce the text size

Answer (score 0):

They are cut off because of the actions you are adding 
try to remove the actions you will get your full 256/64 dp.